# ClassCastException while using list in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying to execute a JPA program in eclipse. I have imported all necessary packages.

This is my POJO(@entity) class

```
@Entity
public class Student
{
    int id,marks;
    String name;
    Student(int i, int j, String k)
    {
        id=i;marks=j;name=k;
    }
    public int getMarks()
    {
        return marks;
    }
    public void setMarks(int i)
    {
        marks = i;
    }
}
```

This is a portion of my 'main' class

```
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("database/database.odb");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        Student s1;
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        s1 = new Student(1,100,"abcd");
        em.persist(s1);
        s1 = new Student(2,200,"efgh");
        em.persist(s1);
        s1 = new Student(3,300,"ijkl");
        em.persist(s1);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        Query q1 = em.createQuery("select marks from Student");
        List<Student> result =  q1.getResultList();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        for(Student s : result)
        {
            if(s.getMarks()%200==0)
                em.remove(s);
            else
                s.setMarks(s.getMarks()*2);
        }
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        q1 = em.createQuery("select marks from Student");
        System.out.println("Details of students are : " + q1.getResultList());
```

The output i expect is : [200, 600]
because the marks in the 1st and 3rd record should get multiplied by 2 and the the 2nd record should get deleted.

But I get an error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to assg6.Student at assg6.Main.main(Main.java:52)
```

(My project's package name is assg6)

I tried this

```
List<Student> result =  (List<Student>)q1.getResultList();
```

and

```
for(Student s : (List<Student>)result)
```

Why am I not getting the expected output and how do i get it?

Comment: How is this: [java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to assg6.Student] not a very clear description of what the problem is?

Comment: what is the meaning of java.lang.Integer here? result is not an integer

Comment: @AmeyWaze apparently: it is

Comment: ohh ..... I thought it would be of Student type @Stultuske

Comment: the result is actually the value of mark, not the entire information of the student, and the mark is an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, `q1.getResultList()` is returning a list of Integers. Not surprising, since you're saying `Query q1 = em.createQuery("select marks from Student");`

You probably wanted to write `"select s from Student s"` instead.

Comment: @AmeyWaze Please include line numbers with your code. If not sure how, which is line #52?

Comment: really sorry @Timir     the for loop is line 52

Comment: what is `s` in `select s from Student` ? @Timit

Comment: Sorry, the inline query should've read `"select s from Student s"`

Comment: yeah but still, what is `s` in `select s from Student s` , the first `s` i mean

Comment: For further reading - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/vasiliev-jpql-087123.html.